# WS-Security with PasswordDigest security concern

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I created a WS endpoint which is secured with WS-Security. The client authentication is based on a UsernameToken with PasswordDigest password type (sadly certificate-based authentication is not an option, we have some legacy clients).

Here is sample SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>vCsshCTkiz07lpCZXVYgwXPU7n4=</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>fsf9Vc2YNErZy4Cc2wcYjw==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2013-06-06T09:31:16.757Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rem:start>
            <xxx>111</xxx>
        </rem:start>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As I understand the password is generated as Base64(SHA(Nonce+Created+ClearTextPassword)).

I'm implementing a CXF PasswordCallback for giving the correct cleartext password to the CXF framework, so it can calculate its digest value and compare with the supplied one.

```
public class PasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(final Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

        final WSPasswordCallback passwordCallback = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
        passwordCallback.setPassword("cleartextpassword");

    }

}
```

My concern is that I must set the password value as plain text, and thus I have to store them (my use-case: in the database) in clear text.

I have the feeling that this is the best that I can get with this PasswordDigest scenario, but I'm inclined to know if there is a better alternative...

Thanks!

M.